# onDraw Triangle works only when orientation is south or east

Tags: android, xml

I've implemented a custom class that extends view and draws a triangle. The code works fine for direction North and West, but fails on South and East and I can't get a logical explanation why, it makes no sense. Any idea guys? Thank you.

```
public class Triangle extends View {

Paint mPaint;

Path mPath;

public enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
}

public Triangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    create();
}

public Triangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    create();
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
}

private void create() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mPath = calculate(Direction.SOUTH);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private Path calculate(Direction direction) {
    Point p1 = new Point();
    p1.x = 0;
    p1.y = 0;

    Point p2 = null, p3 = null;

    int width = getWidth();

    if (direction == Direction.NORTH) {
        p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
        p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y - width);
    } else if (direction == Direction.SOUTH) {
        p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
        p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y + width);
    } else if (direction == Direction.EAST) {
        p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
        p3 = new Point(p1.x - width, p1.y + (width / 2));
    } else if (direction == Direction.WEST) {
        p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
        p3 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y + (width / 2));
    }

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);

    return path;
 }
}
```

Comment: Look at `NORTH`, for example. You have `p3`'s `y` set at `p1.y - width`. `p1.y` is `0`, so it's `- width`, which is outside of the `View`'s bounds.

Comment: Fair enough Mike, but how I'm supposed to draw the third point? North and east direction it's -width..

Comment: Figure the `Point`s correctly for the given direction. The top-left corner of a `View` is (0, 0). Only `SOUTH` and `EAST` will have a `Point` there, yeah? For `NORTH`, the top point will be at (width/2, 0). You don't want any of the figured `Point`s to have a negative coordinate, so the other two `Point`s' y-coordinates will be `width`, presumably.

Comment: It isn't working Mike. If the second point is (width,0), the third point can't be (width/2, 0).

Comment: Any idea guys ?

Comment: (width, 0) is the top-right corner of the `View`. Why would `NORTH` have a `Point` there? I don't think you understand the coordinate system correctly. Assuming you're trying to use the width as the main measure, `NORTH` will have `Point`s at (width/2, 0), (0, width), and (width, width).

Comment: Solved it, thanks Mike! North:  (width/2, 0), (0, height), and (width, width)
 East: (width/2,height/2), (width,0), (width,height)